# Kdenlive dark theme on Ubuntu 20.04 (How to Enable?)

Tags: kde, themes, kdenlive

I've got Kdenlive version 20.04.01 on my Ubuntu 20.04 default installation. How do I enable Kdenlive's dark theme? If I go to `Settings > Color Theme` there's only one option "Default" which happens to be a light theme.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1. run `sudo apt install breeze` in terminal
2. Restart **Kdenlive**
3. Goto `Settings` > `Color theme` > `Breeze dark`.